# Spring Boot: Boot Run cannot add addResources = true

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

In Kotlin, on Intellij using gradle to run the task bootRun for Spring Boot, I get the error that follows:

```
 BUILD FAILED

 Total time: 0.085 secs
 Could not set unknown property 'addResources' for task ':bootRun' 
 of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun.
```

I am using kotlinVersion = '1.1.4-3', springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M3' and my bootrun task looks like the following in my gradle.build

```
bootRun
    {
         addResources = true
    }
```

My bootRun works as expected without the adjustments to the bootRun task

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot 2.0 where the `addResources` property no longer exists. Instead, you need to set the `sourceResources` property to the source set that you want to use. Typically that’s `sourceSets.main`. This is described in the [plugin’s documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3//gradle-plugin/reference/html/#running-your-application-reloading-resources).

Comment: save my day. Thanks!!